# Nesting haml loops to get "Collapse bootstrap-collapse.js" working properly within Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Having the following rails view (haml):

```
.row
  .span7
    %h1 Listing categories
    %p
      - @categories.each do |category|
        .accordion-group
          .accordion-heading
            .accordion-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "##{category.path}"}= link_to category.name, "##{category.path}"
      - @competitors.each do |category_path, competitors|
        .accordion-body.table.collapse.in{:id => "#{category_path}"}
          %table.accordion-inner
            %thead
              %tr
                %th= "Project"
                %th= "Description"
                %th= "Watchers"
                %th= "Forks"
            %tbody
              - competitors.each do |competitor|
                %tr
                  %td
                    = link_to "#{competitor["html_url"]}".sub( "https:\/\/github.com\/", "" ), "#{competitor["html_url"]}"
                  %td
                    %span »
                    = competitor["description"]
                  %td
                    %span.badge.badge-info= competitor["watchers"]
                  %td
                    %span.badge.badge-warning= competitor["forks"]
```

I need css class `.accordion-group`, to contain both `.accordion-heading` ( which is inside the @categories.each loop ) and `.accordion-body` (which is inside the other loop: `@competitors.each` loop).

Note the two `.each` ruby loops, are at the same "node level" in haml, while their css classes `.accordion-heading` and `.accordion-body` have to be into `.accordion-group` css class container.

The resoulting html which I need, is like the following:

```
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
  <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
  <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
  <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
</div>
...
```

... while I currently get this wrong html code :

```
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
</div>
...
<div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
<div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
<div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="collapse_id">
...
```

I cannot find the right way for indent haml ...

Comment: Are `@categories` and  `@competitors` always the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do something like this in Haml is to get your data into the right format first so that it matches the structure of how it should apear on the page. Then iterate over this structure and the markup should be much easier to create and clearer.

In this case for example, you want to iterate over *pairs* of elements in turn, one from each array, rather than over each array individually. Then you can do something like this, (where `each_pair` isn’t a real method, it’s just for demonstration):

```
- each_pair do |category, competitors|
  .accordion-group
    .accordion-heading
      ...
    .accordion-body
      ...
```

In Ruby, you can combine arrays to get pairs (or triplets or larger) with the [`zip` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), so what you want is something like this:

```
- @categories.zip(@competitors) do |category, (category_path, competitors)|
  .accordion-group
    ...etc...
```

In this case `@competitors` is already an array of arrays, so we destructure it to get the paramaters we want.

Comment: Wow, that's great, I didn't know Enumerable #zip method and never seen a trick like this, thank you. Learned something again, very grateful..

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't indenting your second block (as in below) work ?

```
.row
  .span7
    %h1 Listing categories
    %p
      - @categories.each do |category|
        .accordion-group
          .accordion-heading
            .accordion-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "##{category.path}"}= link_to category.name, "##{category.path}"
        - @competitors.each do |category_path, competitors|
          .accordion-body.table.collapse.in{:id => "#{category_path}"}
            %table.accordion-inner
              %thead
                %tr
                  %th= "Project"
                  %th= "Description"
                  %th= "Watchers"
                  %th= "Forks"
              %tbody
                - competitors.each do |competitor|
                  %tr
                    %td
                      = link_to "#{competitor["html_url"]}".sub( "https:\/\/github.com\/", "" ), "#{competitor["html_url"]}"
                    %td
                      %span »
                      = competitor["description"]
                    %td
                      %span.badge.badge-info= competitor["watchers"]
                    %td
                      %span.badge.badge-warning= competitor["forks"]
```

Comment: I cannot, this would multiplicate each competitors iteration for each categories iteration ...